# When selecting row based on column value got empty row but column value is available in data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

here is my piece of code, this is working well for all other values of column but for one value in column giving empty row , but this value is available in column so row should not be empty

```
EOG_MAX_model=pp.loc[(pp['time']==5.3)]
```

5.3 is available in 'time'column. and datatype is float64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with precision, possible solution is use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
EOG_MAX_model=pp.loc[np.isclose(pp['time'], 5.3)]
```